# seasonal_decompose() in statsmodels can't understand frequent H

Tags: python, r, pandas, time-series, statsmodels

I am trying to predict daily sales using ARIMA models. In order to decompose the time series into three components: random entry, seasonal entry and trend entry, I used `seasonal_decompose` in `statsmodels`. The dataframe is as below.

```
2011-01-18 19:00:00     99
2011-01-18 20:00:00     83
2011-01-18 21:00:00     41
2011-01-18 22:00:00     33
2011-01-18 23:00:00     20
Name: number, Length: 384
```

When I passed the dataframe into `seasonal_decompose()`, it returned the error message as below

[image: error message about seaonal_decompose]

I don't know whether the function support decomposition of daily series. If statsmodels don't support it, any other way?
 Thanks very much :-D

Comment: Please put error messages in code blocks instead of posting an image of the stack trace. Images are not indexed, therefore it is hard for others to find your question.

Comment: There's an open issue for `freq='D'` and I added 'H' to it https://github.com/statsmodels/statsmodels/issues/2109

Comment: as a work around that looses the panda index information, you could use numpy arrays, `seasonal_decompose(data.values, freq=24)` which I guess should work.

Comment: So this issue won't be fixed until version 0.7 and I should use R instead @user333700

Comment: It might not be fixed until version 0.8, and you have to use R a bit longer, or use the work around. (I'm still waiting for someone to open a PR to fix it.)

Comment: was this issue fixed? I have the same issue with `freq D`